# Action attribute in forms is not a url. Why?

Tags: forms, uri

When I check the action attribute of a drupal form, I never see a valid URL. What I see in the html code is a simple string, which usually matches the node title of the form. Given that the action attribute should contain a valid URL pointing to a server-side script, I am really confused! What are the mechanics behind the form's submission? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Provide more details! What version of Drupal? What modules you are using? What themes? I never seen an action OTHER than a valid URL in drupal-generated forms, except theme or module bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you look again, I would hazard a guess that you are using pathauto, and that the default pattern for Webform paths is `[node:title]`. If you set it to `form/[node:title]` then the action attribute would look more like a path. eg. *My Form* would have an action attribute of `action="/form/my-form"`.

In Drupal everything goes through the Drupal bootstrap. There are no calls to cgi-bin or the equivalent. Rendering a form or processing a form are done by calling the same url, which tells Drupal where to look for the form. What Drupal does depends upon the op associated with the call, and the rendering, validation, processing and storage are all defined by the modules underlying the form.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Clean Urls enabled? (admin/config/search/clean-urls)

If it can (dependent on web server used) Drupal likes to re-write its URLs to be more meaningful and human readable, so what you see in the action of a form is not the REAL URL that drupal is going to "receive" when the form is POSTed.